# Spark Pooling Options

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am having trouble understanding how to use the settings for pooling options and being able to tell if they are working from this source: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.4/manual/pooling/

Would the SparkSession val take into account the pooling options from the cluster?

My Scala Code:

```
package com.zeropoints.processing

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster
import com.datastax.driver.core.PoolingOptions
import com.datastax.driver.core.HostDistance

//This object provides the main entry point into spark processing
object main {

  var appName = "Processing" 

  lazy val sparkconf:SparkConf = new SparkConf(true).setAppName(appName)

  lazy val poolingOptions:PoolingOptions = new PoolingOptions()

  lazy val cluster:Cluster = Cluster.builder().withPoolingOptions(poolingOptions).build()

  lazy val spark:SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkconf).getOrCreate

  lazy val sc:SparkContext = spark.sparkContext

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    //Set pooling stuff
    poolingOptions.setConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, 6, 60)

    //DF and RDDs tasks...
    spark.sql("select * from data.raw").groupBy("key1,key2").agg(sum("views")).
        write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(Map( "table" -> "summary", "keyspace" -> "data")).
        mode(org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode.Append).save()

    //..more stuff
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

No, the Spark Connector won't take your pooling configuration into account - it works different way, especially if you think about execution of your code in the distributed environment - your `setConnectionsPerHost` is executed only in driver, and won't affect executors.

The correct way is to specify necessary settings via Spark configuration parameters.  Documentation have a [separate section on connection parameters](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/reference.md#cassandra-connection-parameters), and `connection.connections_per_executor_max` could be what you need. You can also write your own class that implements trait `CassandraConnectionFactory` and provide implementation of the  `createCluster` function. Then you can specify this class name as `connection.factory` configuration parameter.

But the main question is - do you really need to tune these options? Do you think that processing is slow? Java driver doc recommends to have 1 connection per host to avoid putting an additional load to Cassandra.

Comment: Agree completely, its pretty unlikely that increasing connections per host will improve performance.  In testing I've found that you can get some throughput improvement increasing the value, but that's generally only when you are loading at full stop and even then the improvement is pretty marginal.  I'll look into updating the datastax driver documentation to make that more clear.

Comment: Ok, it looks like that your Spark code is reaching the "remote DC" that has a limit of 256 inflight requests by default. You can try to set the `connection.local_dc` parameter to the name of your "local" Casasndra datacenter - in some cases driver isn't able to guess where your code is located.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'll try setting that and see how it goes. Thank you for the assistance